# Some user can't connect to network

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ethernet

I got into work today and found that 5 out of 35 users were not able to connect to the network.  They are all Windows 7 and all are connected to my Windows Server 2008 R2 domain through unmanaged gigabit switches.  To fix the problem I have to find the cable for each user and plug it into a different port on the switch.  The users were on two different switches.  This is the third time I have had this problem.

Can the switches be bad?

Comment: This sounds like cabling problems. Do you have the report from your cable installer?

Comment: I tested the cable with a linkMaster from Ideal and it tested good.

Comment: @RonMaupin - it doesn't sound like OP actually changed cables - they say that they changed ports on the switch.

Comment: @mfinni, the simple act of moving a flaky cable from one switch interface to another can cause it to start working again, for a while.

Comment: We can guess all day. Without more details, we really don't know.

Comment: @GreyHippo, that will give you a simple wire map, which is insufficient today. Modern network cabling takes a very expensive (>$10,000) tester to pass a test suite. Your cable installer will give you a report for each cable run, and you should save those. The tester can be configured to only test the solid-core horizontal cable, a stranded patch cable, and the full channel. You should have such tests saved from the installation.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/42696/8499) gives you the primary tests required for cabling to pass the test suite. Your tester simply doesn't perform most of these tests.

Comment: @RonMaupin - you're also assuming that greyhippo has modern cabling :-)

Comment: @mfinni, I don't see any business still using Category-3 (maximum 10 Mbps) cabling for a network. Any higher category has cable specifications, and it should have reports from the installer. We have some sites with cabling from nearly 20 years ago where we still have the reports on file.

Comment: All of the cat 5 or 5e cable was run by a DIY type person many years ago so I don't have any cable reports.  The tester only tells me if there is a continuity, a short or wire mismatch.

Comment: @GreyHippo, that is really insufficient testing. Only continuity and wire map doesn't really tell you if the cable can work with modern networking. The _ANSI/TIA/EIA 568 Commercial Building Telecommunications Cabling Standard_ has been around for decades, and it is regularly update to add new cabling standards. A business that depends on its network should have proper cabling. You can hire a certified installer for a few hours to test your cabling and provide the reports, and he can correct problems that are reported.

Comment: Yup, GreyHippo's company can and should invest in good wiring, it's fundamental. It may also not be the problem they're seeing. Need more troubleshooting details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the switches could be bad. Without managed switches, you'll have a very tough time doing any kind of diagnosis.

You've also given us absolutely no details to work with. "not able to connect to the network" tells us nothing. Was the link light out? Did they not get valid DHCP assignments? Would a static IP work if you tried it? Do other workstations work OK on the ports you removed the non-working machines from?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details.  For most of your questions my answer would be "i dont know".  The next time this happens I will have answers to your questions.